# Install Google Play on Eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, emulation, google-apps

I'm trying to Install Google play on my Eclipse Emulator, but It don't work. The Google play icon does not appear when I start my emulator.

I have followed the guide for setting up Google Play Services: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

I there any options to be made on my emulator to get It work? Should I use the Google APIs as Target In my emulator? Currently I have these settings:

Device: Nexus 5
Target: Android 5.1.1 - API Level 22
CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86_64)

Is there any additional packages or something that I must Install to get It work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be one bundle file that needs to be installed into your system and just drag that bundle file to your emulator.

I am using genymotion for testing my apps and it is used for quick response.

I have tried and it works fine for me.

Any queries and suggestions you need, feel free to contact me without any doubt.

Comment: I have now Installed genymotion :). It works perfect!

Comment: Hmmm. I hope this answer works for you. And genymotion is totally gives you the quick response at a time. Justa because it is very fast for teating any app.